# Blueprism - Syncing issues in object studio and process studio

Tags: blueprism

Tried automating a hotel booking website, on the webpage all the elements interaction works fine when run from object studio, but when the same object is called from process studio, few values are missed like it skips entering the to and from date and directly presses search button. How to handle it ? I tried using wait stage in object studio but no help

Comment: Sometimes the values provided in object studio are not passed in process studio, it enters random values instead of what is hardcoded in object studio

Answer (score 0):

Well, if something does work in object studio and does not work in process studio, then 99% of the time an issue with wait stages. Please investigate further in that area.

Comment: Thanks, there is another issue, When I get any error in process studio, I go to object studio on that stage and when I try to run that step from object studio it says application is not connected, is there a way to connect application at that point to object studio ?? because it was launched from process studio and I have already navigated to many pages and in the middle of any process, how to debug it from object studio without launching it from beginning?

Comment: Yes, when debugging the process then you can enter the objects in two ways.The first way is by right clicking the object box and choosing "View action in Object Studio". The other on is using "step action" - the hotkey is F11 button. The big difference is that using the second one, you will be connected and have filled input variables. There are of course many more differences,

Answer (score 0):

Put a wait stage in object studio wherever necessary(for example when we are navigating to other pages etc). 
hope it will solve your problem.